# Can't pass data from octave to python through command line arguments

Tags: python, subprocess, octave

I am calculating HoG feature descriptors in **Octave** and then I am trying to cluster those data in **Python** using **scikit-learn**.
For testing my code in **Python** I am trying to pass a 4000x2 data to **Python**.
I am calling the **Python** script from **Octave** using

`system('python filename.py data')`

and then trying to get the data using

`sys.argv`

but I am getting the second argument as a string **'data'** and not the 4000x2 data that I am passing from **Octave**

What should I do so that I can get the original data in **Python** and not just the string **'data'**

Comment: I don't know Octave but probably because you are using single quotes `'python filename.py data'` the system function is taking it as a string. I dont know i you can pass to system something like `system('python filename.py ' + data)` You need to tell to `system` that `data` is a variable, not a string.

Comment: You may also consider writing your data to a file in a common format like csv from your octave script (https://octave.sourceforge.io/octave/function/csvwrite.html) and then access it from your python script.

Comment: @fvidalmolina the method you said isn't working because python is trying to concatenate the data as a string to the string 'python filename.py'

Comment: @voidpointercast your method worked. Writing to a csv file and then reading it by importing pandas, did the job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a `python` command built into octave.
Alternatively, I would save as a `.mat` file, and open this in your python script using `scipy.io.loadmat`.

There's also [`eval_py`](https://octave.sourceforge.io/symbolic/function/evalpy.html) and [`python_cmd`](https://octave.sourceforge.io/symbolic/function/python_cmd.html) from the [symbolic package](https://octave.sourceforge.io/symbolic/index.html), but I'm not sure if this is appropriate for your particular use-case. The most general, matlab-compatible, and recommended way to do this would be the `.mat` one.

Comment: Writing to a `.mat` file and reading through `scipy.io.loadmat` worked

Comment: But I am not getting how the `python` command works.

I am using this code 

`python('filename.py',data)`

But I am getting the error 


`error: python: invalid arguments
error: called from
    python at line 48 column 5`

Comment: As I understand it, the `python` command works as if you had called `python arg1 arg2 arg4 etc` from the terminal. Therefore your arguments need to be strings, and you would process them appropriately from inside the python script, same way as if you had called the python script from the terminal. Best to stick to `.mat` files. Fancier interfaces communicating between python and octave (e.g. oct2py) use sockets under the hood to achieve byte data transfer.

Answer (score 1):

I am not an expert regarding Octave but the answer is most likely something like that:

```
command=sprintf("python filename.py %s",data)
system(command)
```

Be careful that the amount of command line arguments is limited in most operating systems.

Comment: I tried getting the arguments using `sys.argv` and tried printing the data in python using the method you advised. But it is only printing strings 'python filename.py' multiple times as a list like 

`['filename.py','python','filename.py','python','filename.py','python','filename.py']`

Comment: What does octave show when you print command to console? Could you provide the main section of your python script?